# Why my XPath assertion test does pass in eXist-db?

Tags: unit-testing, xpath, exist-db

I have a testing function which takes a document as its argument and transforms it from XML into HTML. For it, I would like to use some tests. `%test:assertXPath` seems to be a good candidate in this case. However, I can’t understand its behavior if I use the whole path.

My function:

```
xquery version "3.0";

module namespace cust = 'http://46.28.111.241:8081/exist/db/apps/myapp/modules/cust';

declare namespace tei  = 'http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0';
declare namespace test = 'http://exist-db.org/xquery/xqsuite';
declare
    %test:args('<TEI xmlns="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0">
                    <text>
                        <body>
                            <div n="1">
                                <head>Heading</head>
                                <p>paragraph</p>
                            </div>
                        </body>
                    </text>
                </TEI>',
                '/db/apps/myapp/resources/xslt/style-web.xsl')
    %test:assertXPath('$result//@*')
    %test:assertXPath('$result//*')
    %test:assertXPath('$result//*[@class = "chapter"]')
    %test:assertXPath('$result/html')
function cust:transform($doc as element(), $styleSheet as xs:anyURI) as node() {
    let $styleSheet := doc($styleSheet)
    let $document := 
        (
            <book n='1'>{($doc//tei:div[@n='1'])[1]}</book>
        )
    let $finale := transform:transform($document, $styleSheet, ())
    return $finale
};
```

The result:

```
<testsuites>
    <testsuite package="http://46.28.111.241:8081/exist/db/apps/myapp/modules/cust"
        timestamp="2016-03-17T09:14:40.107+01:00" failures="1" pending="0" tests="1" time="PT0.449S">
        <testcase name="transform" class="cust:transform">
            <failure message="assertXPath failed." type="failure-error-code-1">$result/html</failure>
            <output>
                <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
                    <head>
                        <title/>
                        <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
                    </head>
                    <body>
                        <div id="wrapper">
                            <section xmlns:epub="http://www.idpf.org/2007/ops" epub:type="chapter">
                                <h1 class="chapter">Heading</h1>
                                <p>paragraph</p>
                            </section>
                        </div>
                    </body>
                </html>
            </output>
        </testcase>
    </testsuite>
</testsuites>
```

It is apparent the only one assertion which does not pass is the `$result/html`. Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your missing the namespace from your XPath assertion. The `<html>` element you are producing is in the `http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml` namespace.

So you need to change your assertion to either:

```
%test:assertXPath('$result/*:html')
```

or you need to declare the namespace prefix in your prolog using `declare namespace xhtml = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml";` and then your assertion would look like:

```
%test:assertXPath('$result/xhtml:html')
```

Comment: Interesting. Right now I was closing another one answer regarding to namespaces and **default** namespaces. I will let you know.

Comment: Option 1 fails, option 2 throws an error: `<error type="err:XPST0081" message="It is a static error if a QName used in an expression contains a namespace prefix that cannot be expanded into a namespace URI by using the statically known namespaces."/>`. Am I missing something?

Comment: You have forgotten to declare the namespace declaration your prolog.

Comment: I thought the first option should work without the declaration, in the case of the second option, I have it there: `declare namespace xhtml = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml";`. ?

Comment: Still no progress. I would expect even the basic `%test:assertXPath('$result//*[local-name()="html" and namespace::*="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"]')` could work without any additional declaration in the prolog. If I could provide next examples of the code, I will. At the moment, I don’t know how to do that in a reasonable way here.

Comment: That looks like a  strange use of the namespace axis. I would avoid that.

Comment: At the moment, nothing works for me, hence these desperate attempts.

Comment: `%test:assertXPath('$result//*[local-name(.) eq "html"])` works here

Comment: Thanks a lot, however, it fails in my case: `<failure message="assertXPath failed." type="failure-error-code-1">$result//*[local-name(.) eq "html"]</failure>`. Unhappy. (I have also added the missing quotation mark.)

Comment: Could I use something similar to test that? Still no success.

Comment: @HonzaHejzl Maybe you could study the examples to see some that work: https://github.com/eXist-db/exist/tree/develop/test/src/xquery

Comment: Thanks, this helped a lot! Now I see what is needed. Everything works except one tiny detail—I can’t use paths starting from root with predicates: `/ns:html/ns:head/ns:title` passes, `/ns:html/ns:head/ns:title[. = "Tested Bunny"]` fails.